# Why SVN Diff is taking 10 hours in Crucible

Tags: svn, diff, atlassian-crucible

Good Day All,
My team has two servers, one for crucible and one for SVN. Recently we have had developers complain that their SVN revision are taking a long time to show up in Crucible, sometimes will take up to 24 hours. We really would like this time to be on the scale of minutes. Here is a screenshot from our Crucible UI detailing some of the errors and timeouts i noticed.

The most concerning part is why this command "svn diff --summarize -r 6347:6348 " is timing out after so long, it shouldn't take anywhere near that long to complete.

Any advice or pointers as to why an SVN Diff would take so long and how to reduce?

[image: CrucibleScreenshot]

Comment: we have the same, we are indexing our svn since half a year now and the percentage started going down from 50 to 49.6. Crucible does not work for repos with more than a few hands full of developers.